# Comparing Integer with current year haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function in the module I'm writing that needs to compare the year in a particular custom data with the current year.

```
 removeOld :: Publication -> Bool
 removeOld (PubE (y) s s' _) = if y > 1999 then True else False
```

this function is used with a filter to remove unwanted data. In my case all the publications that are older than 5 years.
I know that the function that takes the current date always returns an "IO type", but in this case there are no side effect for this function and I was wandering if there is a chance to compare the current year with the year in the Data.

I would like the function to look like

```
 removeOld :: Publication -> Bool
 removeOld (PubE (y) s s' _) = if (currentYear - y) < 5 then True else False
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not just return `(y > 1999)` or `(y > currentDate)` as this already is a Bool?

Comment: Good point, but my question is about getting the current Date which I do not have.

Comment: That's why I put a comment, and not an answer. My suggestion is receiving the `currentYear` as a parameter to the `removeOld` function. You might even use currying.

Comment: can you show me how you would do that please?

Comment: I've created an answer.

Comment: You’ll need to pass the current year to `removeOld` from something in `IO` or otherwise make `removeOld` a `Publication -> IO Bool`.

Comment: If it doesn't take the current year as an argument, but it still compares to the current year it would have a side effect. If you call it with the same argument, years apart, it would give different answers. This is why it should produce an `IO Bool` value.

Comment: @DavidYoung you give me the best hint possible. Problem Solved. TY all

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `currentYear` as a parameter to your `removeOld` function.

Somtehing like the code below

```
removeOld :: Int -> Publication -> Bool
removeOld currentYear (PubE (y) s s' _) = (y > currentYear)
```

You might then use the code as 
`removeOld 1999` which is a function as your first example.

---

**EDIT: Question changed a bit...**

To get the current date, use some code like this (you need to include `Data.Time.Calendar` and `Data.Time.Clock`):

```
do
    now <- getCurrentTime
    let (year, month, day) = toGregorian $ utctDay now
```

You can then use the `year` in your function, or use the code above in your function.

Comment: Ok I get where I failed in the explanation.
The problem I have is that I do not want a fixed value like 1999 but I want to say that if the difference between the current year and the year in the Data is greater than 5 the function should return false else true. My bad. I've changed the question.

Comment: @DavideNava If I understand you correctly, you would like to have the current year inside the removeOld function? That is not possible without changing the function to IO Bool. Hidde's (updated) answer is probably the way to go...

Comment: I must have a Bool return type, otherwise the filter will not work. 
Can you guys try to make a function that returns the current year as Int? I tried but I always have problems with type

Comment: In Hidde's example year is of type Integer. But, getCurrentTime is of type IO and there cannot be a safe function that returns the year/date without doing IO. If you put his example code e.g. in main, it'll work and the function removeOld can be without IO. There is no other (safe) way in Haskell.